# SQL Sum Case when State equals

Tags: sql

I'm looking for SQL coding that will sum the count when a certain state appears and have that sum for the state's particular row. I was able to create two columns to sum the count for a specific state but then that number is in every row.

For example, if there are 24 Arizona records then I went 24 to appear in every row for Arizona. And if there are 58 Oregon records then I want 58 to appear in every row for Oregon. And so on...

This is what I currently have

```
select appid,  rcvddt,  state,
       sum(count(case when state = 'OR' then 1 else null end)) over () as  ORcount,
       sum(count(case when state = 'AZ' then 1 else null end)) over ()  as AZcount
from smbus.submissions
where (apprcvddt >= '2017-08-01' and apprcvddt <= '2018-08-31')
group by    state,  rcvddt, appid
order by (case when state is null then 1 else 0 end), state
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `count()` as a window function:

```
select s.*,
       count(*) over (partition by state) as state_cnt
from smbus.submissions s
where apprcvddt >= '2017-08-01' and apprcvddt <= '2018-08-31'
order by (case when state is null then 1 else 0 end), state
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't now about partition. I'll definitely be using this a lot more!

 `count(*) over (partition by state) as state_cnt`

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to get percentages out of the total from this code?

Comment: @go.surf13 . . . Perhaps you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.